# Rendering Flask template show the HTM page twice

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask route rendering a template (method1_result.html) containing a dataframe table. Clicking the table row will send the cell value to another flask route to render a new template (method2_result.html). This last operation is showing a new result relevant to the Cell Clicked but the new html page (method1_result.html) is displaying the result twice.

```
main.py
@app.route("/method1",methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def method1():
   
    '
    '
    return render_template('method1_result.html')

@app.route("/method2",methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def method2():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
     # get info here to render page!
        .
        .
        return render_template('method2_result.html',var1=var1)
```

method1.html

```
{% block content %}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
        <h3 align="center" style="color:blue" style="font-family:verdana">Method1 Result</h3> 
<br/>

<div class="container-fluid">
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            {% for header in table[0].keys() %}
            <th>{{header}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in table %}
        
        <tr class='clickable-row'>
            <td>{{row['Field1']}}</td>
            <td>{{row['Field2']}}</td>
            <td>{{row['Field3']}}</td>
            <td>{{row['Field4']}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
highlight_row();
function highlight_row(var1='') {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        // Take each cell
        var cell = cells[i];
        // do something on onclick event for cell
        cell.onclick = function () {
            // Get the row id where the cell exists
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;

            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            rowSelected.className += " selected";

            msg = 'The Failure Message : ' +   rowSelected.cells[6].innerHTML;
            var var1 = rowSelected.cells[3].innerHTML;
            
            $.ajax({
            url:"/method2",
            method:"POST",
            data:{var1:var1},
            success:function(data)
            { 
                $('tbody').html(data);
                $('tbody').append(data.htmlresponse);
            },
        })
           
        }
    }
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

method2.html

```
{% block content %}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br/>
<h4 align="center" style="color:blue" style="font-family:verdana">Method2 result</h4><br/>
<br/>

<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 100%">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            {% for header in table1[0].keys() %}
            <th>{{header}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in table1 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{row['Start']}}</td>
            <td>{{row['OperationID']}}</td>
            <td style="color:red">{{row['Failure Message1']}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Not sure what Am doing wrong ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by - it is showing the result twice. What exactly would you like the output to look like? Do you want to see only the new page or what?

Comment: instead of showing one html table with a table content, I see 2 similar views on one page.

Comment: I just need to see one page rendered with one table as a result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your code, you are doing an asynchronous call (ajax). An asynchronous call does not reload a page. This means that user is still on `method1_result.html` when the result (i.e. `method2_result.html`) comes in.
2. Your code also says to simply append the entire `method2_result.html` to `method1_result.html` page. In fact, you do it twice because you have

```
    // First you append the entire response i.e. the entire method2 result
    $('tbody').html(data);
    // Then you try to do it a second time but just the 'htmlresponse' (not sure where you are getting this fro
    $('tbody').append(data.htmlresponse);
```

3. If you want to replace the entire page (method1_result) with the entire contents of method2_result, then you don't need an Ajax call. Replace that ajax call with code that creates a form, creates an input element with the values of the data that you want to pass to the server, and then submits the form. Since this is not an ajax call, it will load a new page which is method2.html

```
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "/method2";   

    var elem = document.createElement("input"); 
    elem.name= var1;
    elem.value= var1;
    
    form.appendChild(elem1);  
    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
```

4. If you don't want to replace the entire page (maybe you want to replace the body of the existing page with the new page), then you can't just do `append` which means to add to the existing content, unless you have first cleared the existing content. You have 2 options

Option 1

```
    $('tbody').empty() // Remove the current contents
    $('tbody').append(data); // Add the new contents
```

Option 2

```
    $('tbody').html(data)
```

Comment: Option1 and 2 still show the page with duplicated content. document.createElement is showing exactly what I want to see but not passing the variable var1 to flask route.

Comment: add a screenshot where it shows the duplicated content. Also search stackoverflow for how to create a form and submit it on the fly via javascript. It is possible I missed something but my code is just for reference

Answer (score 0):

Double check your Jinja2 templates in method2.html. Make sure each block is closed.

`{% block content %} {% endblock %}`

That's what did it for me.